# Getting values from a <ul>, <li> tree format

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've the folloing tree view:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<ul id="myTreeSelector" onClick="getPath()">
  <li>
    <span class="caret folder-selector"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> first_folder</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> app1.dat</li>
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> app2.dat</li>
      <li>
        <span class="caret folder-selector"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> second_folder</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> ret.dat</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Which generates a folder tree like this:

[image]

What I'm loking for is that when I click on any file or folder, get the "full file/folder path". This means:

- If I click in `app1.dat`, my desired output is: `first_folder/app1.dat`
- If I click in `second_folder`, my desired output is: `first_folder/second_folder`
- If I click in `ret.dat`, my desired output is:  `first_folder/second_folder/ret.dat`

How can I archieve this? I tried with no luck to get the value:

```
function getPath() {
    var value = $("#myTreeSelector").val()
    console.log(value)
}
```

**EDIT:** The tree can have more than 2 levels, this is just a minified example.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with the plugin you use

Comment: Because right now you do not have anything that has a .val() - .text() yes, but not .val()

Comment: If it helps for the solution, I dont mind adding as `value=` the HTML (file and folder names) text itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made you a snippet. That makes it easier to try to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is generic code, all you need to do is add event to li (using event delegation) and use parents to the li elements that are parents of selected li element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myTreeSelector').on('click', 'li', function() {
     var item = $(this);
     var path = [];
     if (item.is('.file')) {
        path.push(item.text().trim());
     } else {
        path.push(item.find('> .folder-selector').text().trim() + '/');
     }
     var parents = item.parents('#myTreeSelector li');
     path = parents.map(function() {
        return $(this).find('> .folder-selector').text().trim();
     }).get().reverse().concat(path);
     console.log(path.join('/'));
     return false;
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<ul id="myTreeSelector">
  <li>
    <span class="caret folder-selector"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> first_folder</span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> app1.dat</li>
      <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> app2.dat</li>
      <li>
        <span class="caret folder-selector"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> second_folder</span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> ret.dat</li>
          <li><span class="caret folder-selector"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> third_folder</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but it fails when you have an empty folder with no files on it. Try to add `<span class="caret folder-selector"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> second_folder</span>` after the `<li class="file"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> ret.dat</li>` line. I get an `Uncaught TypeError: this.parentElement.querySelector(...) is null`

Comment: @Avión it works, see my edit, did you wrap the element with li, this is how you create list item.

Comment: You are right, I was missing the `<li>` wrap. Thanks a lot!